# How to get the public URL of the image from AWS s3?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3

I design a website by ASP.Net 4.7 and want to get image from AWS S3 public URL.
I only want to show the image on my website and don’t want to download image in my windows server to show.

Could someone tell me how to do it?
I have tried to AWS getObject methods, but it is a kind of download method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well remember that all S3 public URLs are formed like this:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/[BUCKET-NAME]/[FILE-NAME].[FILE-TYPE]
```

So if you know your bucket name and file name while uploading then you can construct your public URL like the above.

```
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/[BUCKET-NAME]/[FILE-NAME].[FILE-TYPE]" />
```

Comment: ...and then just use it in an `<img>` tag.

Comment: Can I encrypt the bucket name on the public URL of the image?

Comment: @DavidLin69 - You can name the bucket whatever you want as longa s it's not already taken by someone else.

Comment: The latest method of doing this is as follows.

https://[application.bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/[key]

eg: https://mybucket-example-com.s3.amazonaws.com/userid/images/test.jpg